# Possible bug in Review Section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-history

I'm a newbie here in Meta. I just got the privilege to Review others' Q&A in Stackoverflow and I've noticed something that could be a bug.

I reviewed 2 Posts, then there was no Post to review anymore. Well, after this I can't see my reviewed Posts in reviews history:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats

It shows 0 reviews both in All Time and Today's lists.

Comment: Caching. Always caching. =) (This may or may not actually be the answer. I'm just abusing memes.)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too :) But I guess it's something different, because the first time it showed the right data, then nothing.

Comment: Your [activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2425452/andreaoid?tab=activity&sort=reviews) shows that you reviewed 2 posts from the 'late answers' queue. I guess now you are looking into the stats of 'first posts' queue. Please confirm.

Comment: Just to be clear, you reviewed two posts and then saw yourself in the daily first-posts/stats, but with 0 reviews to your credit? I believe the stats _are_ cached, however appearing there with 0 reviews to your credit is quite off. The list, however has churned enough since then that I can't see this reproduced (you're no longer on it, as quite a few folks have completed 20 reviews since you posted). But if I did describe it accurately, it might be something we can spot.

Comment: @Aziz-Shaikh: it's exactly as you wrote.
For Tim-Post: in this page http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats I see 0 in Today, All Time and beside the review bar.

Comment: I would say [meta-tag:status-norepro]. Next time take screenshot. :)

Comment: I have the screenshots, but I can't post them since I have not enough reputation :) (minimum = 10).

Update: now I have 6 approved reviews and it's writing 4 on the other page. I don't know if it can help, maybe it's just a banal caching issue (server-side I mean, not local for sure).

Comment: I suspect some were audits. Maybe.

Comment: @Skliwz: no, if with audit you mean fake answers to check user attention, because they're actually in my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens sometimes.

It is mainly because of more than one people being allowed to review the same thing.

It happened with me before I realized that other people were reviewing the same things and someone might have completed the review task before me. In that case I think it should be counted as that person's review not mine. Same goes for you.

Comment: It's not like that because my 2 reviews are already confirmed. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2425452/andreaoid?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: @Andreaoid Then it is something to do with caches. I had placed a bounty and it didn't show up. I asked a question and I was told that the question list is cached. It might be true in this case also.

Comment: Yes, most probably it's just cache.